# Genitive of Sunrise: Sunrise' or Sunrise's

Tags: possessives

I just don't like 'Sunrise's' very much. I want to write "Sunrise' breaking light over the plains" but I'm not sure if it should really be "Sunrise's breaking light over the plains." Whaddaya think?

Comment: How about "The sun rose, breaking light over the plains"?

Comment: *Sunrise'* is not possible, even if you call "poetic license."

Comment: @TinfoilHat Absolutely, 'sunrise' is a singular noun and doesn't even end in 's. The only use of a trailing possesive apostrophe relating to sunrise would be when speaking of more than one sunrise, for instance "He realised that the quality of the sunrises' light differed from day to day". I don't like my example much but it's the best I can do at the moment.

Comment: Don’t do it; it is wrong, misleading and pointless. Consult any grammar guide or search this site for explanation of possessives of nouns that end in “s”. It is foolish to seek to apply such rules to words that merely sound as if they end in “s”. The apostrophe is a written symbol so has no relevance to sound.